# Django decorator @permission_required

Tags: python, django, permissions, decorator

I'm new to Django. I'll be appreciate if anyone can help me.
When I was trying to use the decorator `@permission_required` in a view in Django, it always told that my app name is not defined.
I put this before a view in

request/views.py:

```
@permission_required(request.change_part_status)
```

and got this error

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Do I have to import something or is there something I missed?

Comment: Permission_requires should take the appname as parameter. Why you are putting "request" there?

Comment: `@permission_required('myapp.mypermission')` - argument is supposed to be string.